# how to send more than 1 parameter in set rules to a public function in codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

reference link is this:

[Check duplicate data in CodeIgniter try to make a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493043/check-duplicate-data-in-codeigniter-try-to-make-a-callback-function)

and this is my controller:

```
function saveData(){
    $value = $this->input->post('Id');
    $fromtable = 'tbl_tablename';
    $fromwhere = 'Id';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('productId', '', 'callback_check_duplicate_record[' . $value,$fromtable,$fromwhere . ']');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Record already exists.');
        redirect('addNew');
        return;
    }
}
public function check_duplicate_record($value,$fromtable,$fromwhere) {

return $this->user_model->checkRecordExists($value,$fromtable,$fromwhere);

}
```

this works fine with 1 parameter, but how to send 3 parameters.

where am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you aren't doing anything wrong per-say, it's just that the callback function is only designed to handle 1 parameter.

since two of your values are hard-coded you don't really need to pass them technically.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('productId', '', 'callback_check_duplicate_record[' . $value . ']');

public function check_duplicate_record($value) {
    $fromtable = 'tbl_tablename';
    $fromwhere = 'Id';
    return $this->user_model->checkRecordExists($value,$fromtable,$fromwhere);
}
```

and to be honest it doesn't even look like you need form validation as your only validator is the callback, just use that:

```
if (!$this->user_model->checkRecordExists($value,$fromtable,$fromwhere)) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Record already exists.');
        redirect('addNew');
        return;
}
```

Comment: is there a better way to validate this while entering data in form on its focus loss without refreshing the page. probably its part of ajax, how do I implement the ajax

Comment: that's another question for the js/ajax tag but yea it would involve ajax and jquery. pretty easy ajax to do so its a good starter for someone who is new to using it.